# BottomSheet behaviour is not Supporting in Design support library 25.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My App build.gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

I added `BottomSheet` and it is working fine with `Design support library 23.4.0` but when I upgrade it to `25.0.1` it will not work.

Comment: Maybe you made an error somewhere  I have been using support librery 25.0.0; it is working fine.

Comment: have you change the `compileSdkVersion 23` to 25 and `targetSdkVersion 23` to `targetSdkVersion 25` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'` to `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'`?

Comment: yes I changed my CompileSdkVersion and TargetSdkVersion.